# How does climbing ledges via the ropes work?

Tags: worms-revolution

I'm still having some issues with the new Ninja Rope physics. My biggest problem is I can't seem to reliably climb up over a ledge. According to the tutorial you just hold right/left in the direction of the ledge. This sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, and the worm seems to take a widely variable amount of time before jumping up onto the ledge.

Is there some trick to this? Do I need to be a certain distance to the ledge to be able to jump? Do I need to wait a certain amount of time or what? If it matters, I'm mostly concerned with climbing ledges where my rope is attached just at/below the cliff edge. If I'm attached above the cliff I can *usually* swing over and onto the ledge with a jump.

Comment: Obligatory rage that the ninja ropes are ruined forever, things aren't like they used to be etc

Comment: There are emulators for people like you.

Comment: @fredley I actually have Worms and Armageddon on PS3. Revolution is still fun (especially the water) but the new rope and jetpack physics are just...bad.

Comment: I'd like to know why they think it's a good idea for each game (since Armageddon) to have less weapons/modes/customizations than the last.